# Opposite CertAddEncodedCertificateToSystemStore to get ASN1 certificate out of windows certificate store?

Tags: winapi, ssl, openssl, certificate

I need to programmatically retrieve all of the CA certificates in the Windows certificate store for use in OpenSSL. Win32 has a function called CertAddEncodedCertificateToSystemStore which does the exact opposite of what I need:

```
BOOL WINAPI CertAddEncodedCertificateToSystemStore(
  _In_  LPCSTR szCertStoreName,
  _In_  const BYTE *pbCertEncoded,
  _In_  DWORD cbCertEncoded
);
```

CertAddEncodedCertificateToSystemStore creates a PCCERT_CONTEXT from an X509 ASN1 data buffer and adds it to a system certificate store. I need to go through a system certificate store, converting PCCERT_CONTEXTs to X509 ASN1 data buffers.

It looks as though CertSerializeCertificateStoreElement is very close to what I want:

```
BOOL WINAPI CertSerializeCertificateStoreElement(
  _In_     PCCERT_CONTEXT pCertContext,
  _In_     DWORD dwFlags,
  _Out_    BYTE *pbElement,
  _Inout_  DWORD *pcbElement
);
```

...but apparently the data buffer returned by CertSerializeCertificateStoreElement() isn't a proper DER ASN encoding - it has extra 'stuff' - some sort of windows certificate store properties - and I wouldn't be able to use this for converting to OpenSSL X509's.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I was able to use to dump certificates from the System Store. The cleanup objects don't do anything special. They just close handles, free memory, etc. I also yanked out the error checking to keep the size down.

```
HCERTSTORE hCertStore = CertOpenSystemStore(NULL, _T("ROOT"));
CertStoreCleanup cleanup1(hCertStore);

PCCERT_CONTEXT pCertContext = NULL;
CertContextCleanup cleanup2(pCertContext);

while(pCertContext = CertEnumCertificatesInStore(hCertStore, pCertContext))
{
    CHAR filename[256] = {0};
    INT rc = sprintf_s(filename, sizeof(filename), "cert-%02d.der", i);

    FILE* fp = NULL;
    errno_t et = fopen_s(&fp, filename, "w");
    FileCleanup cleanup3(fp);

    BYTE* pCert = pCertContext->pbCertEncoded;
    DWORD dwSize = pCertContext->cbCertEncoded;

    fwrite(pCert, (size_t)dwSize, 1, fp);
}
```

---

Unfortunately, neither Gutmann's `dumpasn1` or OpenSSL's `asn1parse` can handle them. Humorously, Microsoft's own Certificates snap-in cannot parse it. There's a bug report on Microsoft Connect: [CertEnumCertificatesInStore and friends provide a malformed certifcate](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/900049/certenumcertificatesinstore-and-friends-provide-a-malformed-certifcate).

They start out looking normal, but they break midway through parsing. For example, here's Gutmann's `dumpasn1` on the Microsoft Root Certificate:

[image]

OpenSSL's `asn1parse` has the same complaint:

[image]

---

Finally, Microsoft has a few examples at [Using Certificates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa388156%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).